# how to set time in alarm using Eventkit framework in ios 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to add events to calendar with alarm. If any event time is at 9.00 then alarm must be set at 8.45 ,How to add alarm time using EKAlarm.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read the [`EKAlarm` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKAlarmClassRef/EKAlarmClassReference/EKAlarmClassReference.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i just found a description at [techotopia](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_iOS_6_Event_Kit_to_Create_Date_and_Location_Based_Reminders) For set time in alarm using Eventkit framework in ios 6 like:-

```
-(void)createReminder
{
    EKReminder *reminder = [EKReminder 
          reminderWithEventStore:self.eventStore];

    reminder.title = _reminderText.text;

    reminder.calendar = [_eventStore defaultCalendarForNewReminders];

    NSDate *date = [_myDatePicker date];

    EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:date];

    [reminder addAlarm:alarm];

    NSError *error = nil;

    [_eventStore saveReminder:reminder commit:YES error:&error];

    if (error)
        NSLog(@"error = %@", error);

}
```

Hope its helps you :)